# Shell Script : What is the difference of the number of "<" at "read -a"

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have seen `read -a` with two `<<` and three `<<<` . What is the difference ?

For example:

`read -a arr <<"$file"`

`read -a arr <<<"$file"`

Comment: See [Here Documents](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) and [Here Strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `man bash`, search for `<<` and `<<<` for an explanation how they work.

You use `<<` to create *Here Documents*:

> ```
>    Here Documents
>        This  type  of  redirection  instructs the shell to read input from the
>        current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing
>        blanks)  is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then used
>        as the standard input for a command.
>
>        The format of here-documents is:
>
>               <<[-]word
>                       here-document
>               delimiter
> ```

A typical use is to create a file:

```
cat << EOF > file.txt
hello
there
EOF
```

You use `<<<` to create *Here Strings*:

> ```
>    Here Strings
>        A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
>               <<<word
>
>        The word undergoes brace  expansion,  tilde  expansion,  parameter  and
>        variable  expansion,  command  substitution,  arithmetic expansion, and
>        quote removal.  Pathname expansion and  word  splitting  are  not  per-
>        formed.   The  result  is supplied as a single string to the command on
>        its standard input.
> ```

A typical use is to provide a single line to some command as if it's `stdin`, for example:

```
uppercase=$(tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <<< hello)
```

Which is the modern equivalent of the awkward old technique:

```
uppercase=$(echo hello | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
```

(An even more modern way would be `text=hello; uppercase=${text^^}`, but that's not the point here.)

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that the **modern** replacement to `echo hello | tr a-z A-Z` is the bash 4 extension `oldvar=hello; uppercase=${oldvar^^}`. That said, `a-z` is bad practice, making your code needlessly dependent on locale settings -- some locales' character collation orders can have letters before `a` or after `z`; better to use `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I improved and clarified the examples

Comment: Good deal. BTW, slightly safer to quote those so they get passed to `tr` as-is rather than potentially replaced by the shell if you have any single-character filenames matching them when parsed as globs in the local directory.

Comment: @chepner assuming that `$file` is a filename, I cannot make these commands work the way you describe it. The first starts a heredoc (which I have to terminate with a `$file`). The second puts the filename in the variable, not the first line of the file. I'm in BSD btw, if that matters

Comment: Ugh. No idea what I'm thinking of (`<`, I guess, not `<<`.)